# Nginx returns "nginx: [emerg] open() ".../http-common.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in .../ds.conf" and does not start

Tags: nginx

```
× nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-07-29 09:53:30 WIB; 4s ago
    Process: 9182 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 9188 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 46ms

Jul 29 09:53:30 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: Starting nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jul 29 09:53:30 xxxxxxx nginx[9188]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/includes/http-common.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ds.conf:1
Jul 29 09:53:30 xxxxxxx nginx[9188]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 29 09:53:30 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 29 09:53:30 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 29 09:53:30 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Can you please provide your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ds.conf` file and your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to import an Nginx config file ( "/etc/nginx/includes/http-common.conf") that does not exist (or maybe the owner/permissions need resetting on it). That is correctly stopping the server from starting.

Comment: The error message is quite clear here - did you read it line by line, to see if you could work out the problem on your own?